# Incoming calls dialplan with asterisk and chan_mobile

Tags: bluetooth, asterisk, voip

I managed (with very much joy :D) to configure chan_mobile with asterisk 1.8 and my iPhone 4 and outgoing calls work nicely. 
I have issues with automatic answering incoming calls.

This is what my chan_mobile.conf looks like:

```
[adapter]
address = 11:11:11:11:11:11
id = box-1

[iphone]
address = 22:22:22:22:22:22
port = 8
context = from-test-phone
adapter = box-1
```

and in /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf I added

```
[from-test-phone]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

But when I call my mobile phone there is no answer.

The bluetooth device is paired and active

```
# rasterisk
> mobile show devices

ID              Address           Group Adapter         Connected State      SMS
iphone      22:22:22:22:22:22      0     box-1            Yes     Free       No
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you open up Asterisk CLI with rasterisk, run "core set verbose 4" and "core set debug 4" and call your iPhone, what do you get in your terminal?

Comment: ok this is really a mistery, with verbose and debug 4 it works, back to 0 it doens't!!! Anyway really thank you dude :)
`debian*CLI> core set verbose 4
Verbosity was 0 and is now 4
debian*CLI> core set debug 4
Core debug was 0 and is now 4
    -- Executing [s@from-test-phone:1] Answer("Mobile/iphone-6e3e", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@from-test-phone:2] Wait("Mobile/iphone-6e3e", "1") in new stack
    -- Executing [s@from-test-phone:3] Hangup("Mobile/iphone-6e3e", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (from-test-phone, s, 3) exited non-zero on 'Mobile/iphone-6e3e'`

Comment: Don't edit questions with words "SOLVED", but rather provide an answer, so it's highlighted as such automatically.. This is a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was enough to type

```
rasterisk
> core set verbose 4
> core set debug 4
```

thanks user1938742!